# Question on converting sum of absolute values constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have some optimization problem involving sum of absolute values constraint, such as $\sum_{i=1}^{M}|x_i| \le N$. I've read some posting in the past and found some solutions, especially in this one [Minimize sum of absolute value with linear constraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427708/minimize-sum-of-absolute-value-with-linear-constraint)

However, my question is I don't fully understand the intuition behind the first reformulation. To make things simple, assuming I only have 3 $x$'s. Then the constraint becomes $|x_1| + |x_2| + |x_3| \le 10$. Then the reformulation becomes $\sum_{i=1}^{M}y_i \le 10$  and
\begin{align}
y_1 &\ge x_1 \\
y_1 &\ge -x_1 \\
y_2 &\ge x_2 \\
y_2 &\ge -x_2 \\
y_3 &\ge x_3 \\
y_3 &\ge -x_3 
\end{align}

But intuitively, how do we show the reformulation is equivalent? I've gone as far as changing the group of $y_i$'s to
\begin{align}
-y_1 &\le x_1\le y_1 \\
-y_2 &\le x_2\le y_2 \\
-y_3 &\le x_3\le y_3
\end{align}
Then I'm not sure how to proceed...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question says "I have some optimization problem involving sum of absolute values constraint". The question you have linked to has an *objective function* involving the sum of absolute values (with a *linear* constraint). The reformulation given in the accepted answer does not apply directly to your problem (and is unlikely to be helpful except in special cases).

Letting $f$ denote your objective function, your problem is

$$\min_x f(x)\qquad  \text{subject to}\qquad \sum_{i=1}^M|x_i|\leq N $$

The problem in the question [minimize sum of absolute value with linear constraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427708/minimize-sum-of-absolute-value-with-linear-constraint) is

$$\min_x \sum_{i=1}^M|x_i|\qquad \text{subject to}\qquad Ax=b.$$

In your problem, making a substitution $y_i=|x_i|$ will not be helpful unless your objective function has a special form. In particular you want $f$ to involve either terms of the form $g(x_i)$ where $g(x_i)=g(|x_i|)$. For example, if $f(x)=|x_2|e^{|x_1|}$, then you can rewrite the problem

$$\min_x -x_1^2e^{|x_2|}\qquad \text{subject to}\qquad |x_1|+|x_2|\leq 10$$

as

$$\min_y -y_1^2e^{y_2}\qquad \text{subject to}\qquad y_1+y_2\leq 10$$

The solutions to the second problem is $y=(0,10)$ and so the solutions to the first problem are $(0,10)$ and $(0,-10)$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Suppose that $|x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|\leq 10$.  Put $y_i = |x_i|$.  Then $y_i \geq \pm x_i$ and $y_1+y_2+y_3 \leq 10$.
2. Suppose now that $y_i \geq \pm x_i$, and $y_1+y_2+y_3 \leq 10$.  Then $|x_i|=\max\{ x_i, -x_i \} \leq y_i$.  Therefore, $|x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|\leq y_1+y_2+y_3 \leq 10$.

Together, 1+2 show that the projection of the feasible set expressed in terms of the variables $(x,y)$ onto the first block-coordinate (i.e., $x$) is the same as the feasible set of the original problem.  Therefore they are equivalent in this sense.